# How to change Ajax request type and data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I have a table that is loading data via an Ajax request. The Ajax source is being set at initialization.

However, I would now like to change the request type to a POST and include a data object before I force an Ajax reload.

I am doing something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
dt.ajax.type = 'POST';
dt.ajax.data = {<some data here>};
dt.ajax.reload();
```

I am only able to change the Ajax source URL, but that doesn't need to change.

Comment: look at https://datatables.net/manual/server-side and use draw() for refresh your data

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#function) option to define a function to call [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method as shown below:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
      if(some_condition){
         data.param1 = "A";
         data.param2 = "B";
      }

      $.ajax( {
         "dataType": "json", 
         "type": (some_condition) ? "GET" : "POST", 
         "url": "/json.php", 
         "data": data, 
         "success": callback
      });
   }
});
```

This function will be called on initialization and every time you call [`ajax.reload()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29).